# Handle Bootstrap modal hide event in Vue JS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, vue.js, bootstrap-modal, vuejs2

Is there a decent way in Vue (2) to handle a Bootstrap (3) modal hide-event?

I found this as a JQuery way but I can't figure out how to capture this event in Vue:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

Adding something like `v-on:hide.bs.modal="alert('hide')` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Bootstrap uses JQuery to trigger the custom event `hidden.bs.modal` so it is not easily caught by Vue (which I believe uses native events under the hood).

Since you have to have JQuery on a the page to use Bootstrap's native modal, just use JQuery to catch it. Assuming you add a `ref="vuemodal"` to your Bootstrap modal you can do something like this.

```
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
  },
  methods:{
    doSomethingOnHidden(){
      //do something
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    $(this.$refs.vuemodal).on("hidden.bs.modal", this.doSomethingOnHidden)
  }
})
```

[Working example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/VpvzGO?editors=1010).

Comment: I had hoped for a cleaner (non jquery) solution but this is probably what I'll use until something better pops up ;)

Comment: FYI - If you happen to have another Vue tag that makes this ref="vuemodal" not display, it will not show up in your $refs.  The object with the ref="" has to be rendered in order to work.

Comment: Is it possible to do it in a loop in your experience? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75487110/custom-event-on-each-ref-within-for-loop-vuejs

Answer (score 48):

Please see https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal#overview
There you can find event "hide" or "hidden"
So you can bind this event:

```
<b-modal ref="someModal" @hide="doSometing">
```

Comment: This is the right answer if you're using bootstrap-vue, but that's now that the original question was about. Switching to bootstrap-vue is a pretty significant change that isn't going to be the right answer for everyone.

Comment: The event that worked with me is @closed, but this answer inspired me.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to tie it to a variable:

```
data: function(){
  return {
       showModal: false
        //starts as false.  Set as true when modal opens. Set as false on close, which triggers the watch function.
},
watch: {
  showModal: function(){
    if(this.showModal == false){
     // do something
  },
}
```

HTML

```
<button id="show-modal" @click="showModal = true">Show Modal</button>

 //later if using a component
<modal v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false">

 // or alternatively in the bootstrap structure
<div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" @click="showModal = false">Close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @GufranHasan this wont work if you press the 'Esc' key to hide the modal. In that case your vue instance wont know that the modal is hiding. So the component data 'showModal' will still be true, whereas the modal is now hidden. Now, when you click any button to show that modal again, this wont show up as the ''showModa' is still true, so logically the modal is visible still!! You have to refresh the page. This is exactly why i came to this question hoping to find a solution :(

Answer (score 1):

This may be late but another way if you are using a custom modal component (Modal.vue)  you have created is to

1. create a method in mounted to catch the event of closure (doesn't have to be the same name as below)

```
    mounted: function(){
        this.triggerHidden();
    }
```

2. create the method

```
    methods: {
       triggerHidden: function(){
           var self = this;
           if( $('#getModal').length ){
               $('#getModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
                  //catch the native bootstrap close event and trigger yours
                  self.#emit('modal-close');
               });
           }
        }
    }
```

3. now call use your custom event with your custom/reusable modal component

   `<custom-modal @modal-close="doSomething"></custom-modal>`
   The method doSomething will be called when the modal closes. You can also use the approach to hijack the other jquery event so its a little more manageable.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe creating a Custom Vue Directive can help:

```
Vue.directive('bsevent', {
   bind: function bsEventCreate(el, binding, vnode) {
      let method = binding.value || (() => { });
      $(el).on(binding.arg.replaceAll(/_/g, "."), (event) => { method(event); });
   },
   
   unbind(el, binding) {
      $(el).off(binding.arg.replace(/_/, "."));
   },
});
```

And then just use it on the element you wish (this example is on a bootstrap collapsible, but you could use it to any other bootstrap event):

```
<div id="myCollapsible" class="collapse" v-bsevent:hidden_bs_collapse="methodToCall">
  ...                           
</div>
```

The only thing to remember is to register the event with underscores instead of dots (show.bs.modal => show_bs_modal).

Answer (score 1):

Like @abdullah-zafar I'd recommend using native addEventListener rather than JQuery, although I personally combine it with Vue's refs rather than instantiating the modal.

Say in the template you have something like:

```
<div class="modal fade" ref="bsmodal" id="mymodal" tabindex="-1">
```

then in your mounted() function just do:

```
mounted() {
    this.$refs.bsmodal.addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', event => {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

(that's actually the proposed way in BS doc, here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content)

Answer (score 0):

If working with bootstrap-vue then below code snippet will be helpful:

```
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$root.$on('bv::modal::hide', (bvEvent, modalId) => {
      console.log('Modal is about to be shown', bvEvent, modalId)
    })
  }
}
```

for other events please refer to the [official docs.](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal)

Answer (score 0):

Just use native `addEventListener` (Vue 3, Composition API)

template:

```html
<div ref="modalElement" class="modal">
...
</div>
```

script:

```js
import { Modal } from "bootstrap"
import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";

const modalElement = ref(null)
let modal = null;

onMounted(() => {
  modal = new Modal(modalElement.value)
  modalElement.value.addEventListener("hidden.bs.modal", onHidden)
})

function onHidden() {
  // do something…
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use this simple approach like this example

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="openModal = true">Open Modal</button>
    <div v-if="openModal">
      <div class="modal-background"></div>
      <div class="modal-content">
        <button @click="openModal = false">Close Modal</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      openModal: false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```