# Listening for custom events in vuejs component

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vuejs2, vue.js

In a vuejs component, how can I listen for events like those [Twitter Bootstrap uses for the panel expand/collapse functionality](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events)?

```
$('#myCollapsible').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

I expected I'd be able to do something like this with `v-on` but have had no success:

```
div.panel-collapse.collapse.in(role="tabpanel",
  v-bind:aria-labelledby="panelId-heading",
  v-bind:id="panelId",
  v-on:shown.bs.collapse="handleCollapse")
```

Comment: You have to use JQuery to catch a JQuery custom event. Bootstrap uses JQuery to create/fire those events. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512770/handle-bootstrap-modal-hide-event-in-vue-js/42513893#42513893

Comment: You can use [Vue-Strap](https://github.com/yuche/vue-strap) insteado of jQuery and bootstrap.js