# Custom event on each ref within for loop Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I have a loop of data and have a modal for each loop

```
<div ref="vuemodal-{{loop.index}}">
```

It's a bootstrap modal and to each of them I want to bind an event whenever I close the modal

```
 mounted(){
   Object.keys(this.$refs).map((val) => $(this.$refs[val]).on("hidden.bs.modal", 
 this.doSomethingOnHidden))
  }
```

I don't seem to access the object properly

Comment: the ref is not dynamic, it's just a normal string.  try ``<div :ref="`vuemodal-${loop.index}`">``.  This will create refs "vuemodal-0", "vuemodal-1", etc.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, your `ref` is not dynamic, it's a string. So make it dynamic by binding this using the bind (`v-bind` or `:`) operator.

Second thing, mustaches cannot be used inside HTML attributes, so `{{loop.index}}` won't work.

Here is the demo-

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  mounted() {
    Object.keys(this.$refs).map((val) => console.log(val))
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="index in 5" :ref="`vuemodal-${index}`">
    It's a bootstrap modal and to each of them I want to bind an event whenever I close the modal
  </div>
</div>
```