# Bootstrap 5 dropdown events works unexpectedly in Vue.js 3 app

Tags: vuejs3, dropdown, bootstrap-5

As I found that Bootstrap 5 dropdown events works unexpectedly in Vue.js 3 app, I have made 2 versions of Bootstrap 5 dropdown to compare.

This is the HTML part of Vue.js 3 app

```
<main>
    <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown1" v-on="{  'show.bs.dropdown': console.log('1'),'shown.bs.dropdown': console.log('2'),'hide.bs.dropdown': console.log('3'),'hidden.bs.dropdown': console.log('4') }">
        <button id="localeButton" class="btn btn-lg" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
            <span>X</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="localeButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" @click="a('A')">A</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" @click="a('B')">B</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" @click="a('C')">C</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" @click="a('D')">D</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</main>
```

This is the HTML part outside Vue.js 3 app

```
<div class="dropdown" id="dropdown2">
    <button id="button2" class="btn btn-lg" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
        <span>Y</span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="button2">
        <a class="dropdown-item">Q</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item">W</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item">E</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item">R</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the Vue.js 3 app code

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            foo: 'X'
        }
    }, methods: {
        a(n) {
            this.foo = n
        }
    }
}).mount('main')
```

This is the vanilla js part

```
['show', 'shown', 'hide', 'hidden'].forEach(m => {
    document.getElementById('dropdown2').addEventListener(m + '.bs.dropdown', event => {
        console.log(m)
    })
})
```

In Vue.js 3 version, although dropdown itself works fine, dropdown events are fired only if the app is being rendered but not toggling or dismissing the element. In vanilla version, dropdown events are fired as expected.

Comment: You'll need to use a ref to add event listeners for bootstrap's custom events.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42513893/6225326) which still applies to Vue 3.  You do not need to use jQuery, but regular `addEventListener` will work.  I tested locally to confirm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handle Bootstrap modal hide event in Vue JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512770/handle-bootstrap-modal-hide-event-in-vue-js)